# What's with the Monica thing in user names?

Tags: discussion

Could someone explain simply who Monica is or was, and what she did that some people support?

Comment: Here is one brief summary: [Why are there a lot of users with Reinstate Monica in the username?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340868/why-are-there-a-lot-of-users-with-reinstate-monica-in-the-username)

Comment: Type "Monica" and *summary* in Meta, I'm surprised you have only recently noticed. https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Monica%22+summary Don't go back further than **September 2019**.

Comment: I've tried to ignore it but it was like an itch that wouldn't go away.

Comment: you can hear the whole story [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFiQPkdb5Qs)